# Sharethis Customization

Tags: javascript, sharethis

I imagine its a bit of javascript but how do you have the ShareThis widget go straight to the email page like on Mashable?

Comment: It would be helpful if you could post code examples and links on what you are talking about. Not everyone has worked with "the shareThis widget."

Comment: I agree with Pekka.  I have no idea what ShareThis is ._.

Answer (score 2):

Try changing `<span class="st_sharethis"></span>`
to

```
 <span class="st_email_button" displayText="Email"></span>
```

[This link can help](http://help.sharethis.com/customization/chicklets)

Answer (score 0):

I just added ShareThis to Colorbox.  Here is my code.

Add this to your jquery.colorbox.js file (uncompresses/unminified) around line 360 inside the publicMethod.init function just after the $wrap object is defined.

```
// Add shareThis
    $wrap.append(
        $div("ShareThis").append("<span  class='st_facebook_large' ></span><span  class='st_linkedin_large' ></span><span  class='st_twitter_large' ></span><span  class='st_stumbleupon_large' ></span><span  class='st_gbuzz_large' ></span><span  class='st_sharethis_large' ></span><span  class='st_email_large' ></span>")
    );
```

Add this code to your colorbox.css to align a vertical shareThis bar to left side of the browser when a colorbox modal is displayed.

```
/* Custom ShareThis Style by Dylan Valade of pinelakedesign.com */
#cboxShareThis {
    background: #fff;
    padding-top: 25px;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    top: 25px;
    width: 40px;
    z-index: 9999; }
```

Get a ShareThis button from sharethis.com and you'll paste code like this into the pages that launch the colorbox.

```
<script type="text/javascript">var switchTo5x=true;</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://w.sharethis.com/button/buttons.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">stLight.options({publisher:'YOUR_UUID_GOES_HERE'});</script>
```

Comment: i tried your code and honestly not sure what you are trying to do here. Each time the colorbox is called, you want to show the sharethis widget? If so, that is not at all what this question is about.

Comment: You are right, this wasn't answering the question.  Two of the comments mentioned not understanding the context of ShareThis so I was providing an example.